# Add numbers from list of divs into total div

Tags: javascript, html, math, parsefloat

Lets say I have the following:

```
<div id="c1">$10,000</div>
<div id="c2">$21,500</div>
<div id="c3">$1,550</div>
<div id="c4">Total</div>
```

The values in each id are the result of a separate function say c1(),c2(),c3(). I want to add the results of those functions 10,000+21500+1550 and output the total in div id=
c4".
How do I output the total into the last div id="c4" and format it in USA currency e.g $33,050
Thanks

Comment: Do you have the values of `c1(),c2(),c3()` "in-hand" — available to JS at the time you want to do the addition? Or are you asking how you would first scrape the DOM to get those values at some point _after_ `c1(),c2(),c3()` had already written them into the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
(() => {
  const $ = s => document.getElementById(s);
  const c1 = +$("c1").textContent.replace(/\D/g, "");
  const c2 = +$("c2").textContent.replace(/\D/g, "");
  const c3 = +$("c3").textContent.replace(/\D/g, "");
  $("c4").textContent = `Total = $${(c1 + c2 + c3).toLocaleString()}`;
})();
```

```html
<div id="c1">$10,000</div>
<div id="c2">$21,500</div>
<div id="c3">$1,550</div>
<div id="c4">Total</div>
```

Comment: Couldn't quite get that working. Any more help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I updated my code to include a working snippet

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! https://jsfiddle.net/hcanning2012/0zxugat4/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can add the c1-c3 divs into another div and loop over the children of the wrapper element

```html
<div id="c">
    <div id="c1">$10,000</div>
    <div id="c2">$21,500</div>
    <div id="c3">$1,550</div>
</div>
<div id="c4">Total</div>
<script>
    const valuesElement = document.getElementById("c");
    let sum = 0;
    for (const child of valuesElement.children) {
        sum += parseFloat(child.innerText.replace(/\D/g, ''));
    };
    const totalElement = document.getElementById("c4");
    totalElement.innerText = "$" + sum.toLocaleString();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get that working unfortunately

Comment: What's not working, what did you add to your code?

Comment: My mistake. Works great. Thanks!! https://jsfiddle.net/hcanning2012/0zxugat4/4/